# Monthly registrations and registrations with a date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL table containing fixedprice-registrations both monthly and with a certain date, which look like this:

```
id       int(10)
date     date
userid   int(10)
montly   tinyint(1)
price    decimal(10,2)
```

And some data could be

```
id |    date    | userid | monthly | price
 1 | 01/01 2011 |    1   |    1    |  200
 2 | 01/02 2011 |    2   |    1    |  300
 3 | 14/01 2011 |    1   |    0    |  400
 4 | 15/02 2011 |    3   |    0    |  100
 5 | 23/02 2011 |    2   |    0    |  600
 6 | 05/03 2011 |    2   |    0    |  700
```

A monthly registration will always start on the 1st of the month
and if `monthly` is 1 it is a monthly registration, otherwise it only happens once.

And a query could be (just an example)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fixedpriceregistrations` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '01/02 2011' AND '02/04 2011'
```

where I except this output:

```
id |    date    | userid | monthly | price
 1 | 01/01 2011 |    1   |    1    |  200
 2 | 01/02 2011 |    2   |    1    |  300
 4 | 15/02 2011 |    3   |    0    |  100
 5 | 23/02 2011 |    2   |    0    |  600
 1 | 01/01 2011 |    1   |    1    |  200
 2 | 01/02 2011 |    2   |    1    |  300
 6 | 05/03 2011 |    2   |    0    |  700
 1 | 01/01 2011 |    1   |    1    |  200
 2 | 01/02 2011 |    2   |    1    |  300
```

Can I do that in MySQL or how is the best way to do it in PHP?

In PHP I thought about looping through the registrations with a date and add them to a new array, and when the month changes the monthly registrations are being added.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. In the expected output you posted there are several duplicate lines. Moreover, they're not all within the dates that you specify in you example query. Can you tell us more about what your issue is and what you have problems with?

Comment: There must be duplicates as the monthly should be presented each month

Comment: Then I suppose your PHP approach sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with php. I would:

Fetch all the records you need (i.e. since start date) from the table into an array, `$results`.

```
$output = Array();
foreach ($results as $row)
{
    $output[] = $row;
    if ($row['monthly']) 
        while ( ($row['date'] = add_a_month_to( $row['date'] )) < $end_date )
            $output[] = $row;
}
```

Then sort the resulting `$output` array. I leave the sort and the `add_a_month_to` functions to you. Obviously it assumes you're using a sensible (sortable) date format, e.g. `2011-01-13`.

Comment: don't use underscores.. use addAMonthTo

Comment: the world's underscore population is dwindling! save the underscores!